# OpenThread with a nonexistent thread ID

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

Say, if I call [OpenThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a thread ID that no longer exists and get NULL as a result, I can't seem to find a documentation on what would be the error code in GetLastError? My tests on the Windows 8 machine get me `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` instead of the expected `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: Why are you expecting `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`? A thread is not a file.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Many other MS APIs return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` in that case. That is a better way to distinguish between an object that is not found vs. bad input parameters for the API.

Comment: Well, maybe you have an argument, but the function does what the function does - you can't change that. It makes sense to me that if it's expecting a thread handle and you pass it something that is *not* a thread handle, then that's logicially an invalid parameter. No?

Comment: `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` is the expected error code in this situation.

Comment: I would expect `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID` instead, just like `PostThreadMessage()` reports.  Instead of speculating, it is best to just write a quick test and see what `OpenThread()` **actually** reports.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I was relying on the error code to confirm if the thread identified by its ID was still alive (in conjunction with its creation time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation that will tell you what the error code may be set to when `OpenThread` fails. In general, there are very few Win32 functions that document such information. Primarily this is because Microsoft do not want to constrain future development. They do not want developers to take dependencies on the error codes that are returned. They want flexibility to change that behaviour in future versions.

Comment: OK, good point. Just curious then, given a thread ID and its creation time, can I establish if such thread doesn't exist for sure? (I do not have a thread handle.) With this error code ambiguity I cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: It can fail because of access_denied, or for any other reason that I may not know now.

Comment: And so what if it does?

Comment: The thread would exist in that case so I'd get a false negative.

Comment: So what? You still cannot do anything with that thread? It sounds a bit like you've got random thread IDs. What is the real problem?

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `OpenThread` calls the [`PsLookupThreadByThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is documented as returning:

```
STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER      The thread ID was not found.
```

Comment: Nice find. Thank you.